# How can I fix SerializeCql failing to serialize a vec of hashmaps?

Tags: rust, serde, scylla

So I'm using scylla's rust driver, and I'm working on a websocket which lets me send "commands" to it to insert / update / select data. Currently I've gotten pretty much everything to work besides being able to serialize a vec of hashmaps.

When I try I just get this error:

```
ArrayObject: SerializationError(BuiltinSerializationError { rust_name: "alloc::vec::Vec<std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<alloc::string::String, scyllatcp::structs::common::Value>>", got: List(UserDefinedType { type_name: "tokens_type", keyspace: "kstltest", field_types: [("token_", Text), ("created_date", Timestamp), ("ip", Text), ("flags", Int), ("token_id", Text)] }), kind: SetOrListError(ElementSerializationFailed(SerializationError(BuiltinTypeCheckError { rust_name: "std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<alloc::string::String, scyllatcp::structs::common::Value>", got: UserDefinedType { type_name: "tokens_type", keyspace: "kstltest", field_types: [("token_", Text), ("created_date", Timestamp), ("ip", Text), ("flags", Int), ("token_id", Text)] }, kind: MapError(NotMap) }))) })
```

I'm pretty new to rust so I'm unsure how to fix this.

So Currently I've tried:

```rs
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Value {
    Str(String),
    Bool(bool),
    Num(i32),
    Null,
    Array(Vec<Value>),
    Map(Vec<(Value, Value)>),
    Date(String),
    ArrayObject(Vec<HashMap<String, Value>>),
}

impl SerializeCql for Value {
    fn serialize<'b>(
        &self,
        typ: &scylla::frame::response::result::ColumnType,
        writer: scylla::serialize::CellWriter<'b>,
    ) -> Result<
        scylla::serialize::writers::WrittenCellProof<'b>,
        scylla::serialize::SerializationError,
    > {
        match self {
            &Value::Str(ref value) => {
                scylla::serialize::value::SerializeCql::serialize(value, typ, writer)
            }
            &Value::Num(ref value) => {
                scylla::serialize::value::SerializeCql::serialize(value, typ, writer)
            }
            // &Value::Int(ref value) => {
            //     scylla::serialize::value::SerializeCql::serialize(value, typ, writer)
            // }
            &Value::Bool(ref value) => {
                scylla::serialize::value::SerializeCql::serialize(value, typ, writer)
            }
            &Value::Null => {
                scylla::serialize::value::SerializeCql::serialize(&None::<String>, typ, writer)
            }
            &Value::Array(ref value) => {
                scylla::serialize::value::SerializeCql::serialize(value, typ, writer)
            }
            &Value::Map(ref value) => {
                scylla::serialize::value::SerializeCql::serialize(value, typ, writer)
            }
            &Value::Date(ref value) => {
                scylla::serialize::value::SerializeCql::serialize(value, typ, writer)
            }
            &Value::ArrayObject(ref value) => {
                match scylla::serialize::value::SerializeCql::serialize(value, typ, writer) {
                    Ok(value) => Ok(value),
                    Err(err) => {
                        println!("[Error] Failed to serialize ArrayObject: {:?}", err);
                        Err(err)
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which for the most part works besides at the ArrayObject, where I'm getting that issue.

I've also tried making the `Vec<HashMap<String, Value>>` its custom struct, then implementing SerializeCql on that struct, but got the same issue.